# How to disable scroll lock when moving point

Tags: scrolling, point

A strange behaviour happens when I move up or down the point (using the keyboard): Emacs automatically scrolls up or down whenever I pass a certain line threshold. See here:

[image: Scrolling example]

When moving down, at line 20 the scroll locks (until I reach the end of the buffer). When moving up, the threshold is at line 10.

I would like to disable this scroll locking. That is, I would wish the point could move to the top or bottom of the screen withoug auto-locking the scroll. Any ideas? (Using GNU Emacs 24.4.4 in Linux and Mac.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not how Emacs normally behaves. It looks as though you have configures something like `scroll-margin`. From the built-in help:

> Number of lines of margin at the top and bottom of a window.
>   Recenter the window whenever point gets within this many lines
>   of the top or bottom of the window.

Comment: You must be right. I start with `emacs -q`, I don't get the undesired behaviour. Still, I haven't been able to detect the culprit in my init files. I have commented all lines containing "scroll", but with no luck yet. I also changed `scroll-margin` but also with no luck.

Comment: Try to do a "binary search", i.e. mark the first half of the file and do an `eval-region`. If the incorrect behaviour doesn't appear, it should be int he second half. From there, you can select a quarter of the file etc. until you find the culprit. Of course, there is also the risk of it being introduced by the site init files...

Comment: I finally worked it out. The trouble was with the `smooth-scrolling` package. Even without my explicitly loading it from my init files, it got automatically loaded. Just because it was in my `user-emacs-directory` (in fact, it was in my `elpa` directory, inside my `user-emacs-directory`). Is it normal that all packages get autoloaded, unbeknownst to the user?

Comment: @NVaughan That's because you installed that package using the package manager and you have `(package-initialize)` in your init. From https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html "To disable automatic package loading, change the variable package-enable-at-startup to nil."

Comment: @kaushalmodi Oh, great. Thanks. I didn't know that. I had `(package-initialize)` *before* `(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)`, so that's why it didn't work as expected.

Comment: @NVaughan, once a package is installed it should present itself to the user using autoloads etc. but it should not automatically enable itself. The motivation behind this is that a user should be able to install packages without actually using them. (I learned this from a conversation with the people behind Melpa.)